# How to handle new investors, remove exiting investors from a fund

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Heres the situation,

I've begun managing money for a handful of people in crypto markets.  Each have a different sized account.  Right now I am managing all of them individually, its a problem because its not scaleable and is time intensive.

So my question is how can I create something in google sheets to keep track of investor holdings in an overall fund?  say there's 10 investors, each with $10,000.  Each have 10%.  But then a new investor comes in with 5%.  How can I program this into an excel sheet?

Totally stuck.  I need to be able to add/remove people, and adjust the total assets, holdings per person.

Running into a wall, and crypto forums are just exploding with activity. help.

Comment: Hi there @Bruno! I don't understand this question's relationship with Sheets, could you please clarify your issue with it? Please keep in mind that this question could be related to [Personal Finance & Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You just need to keep track of "invested amount per person " and "total invested fund" . % is just its ratio of both.

Comment: Unfortunately it’s not that simple. Just keeping track of % of the fund does not incorporate the time invested for each individual investor. Later investors would be taking gains from earlier investors the moment that % was updated. If one investor invests 100,000 Jan 1st 2020, and 100 investors each invest 1,000 on Dec 31st 2020 but the fund earned $50,000 during that year, all the new investors would dilute the 1st investors gains the moment they invested.

Comment: Mind sharing some sample file to simulate the case? Quite hard reproduce the equation with (my pressumed) understanding.. afiak.. from the original post I can read [ "investor list" ," invested fund" & "holdings per person" & total assets ] as the input/value involved.. Your comment indicate otherwise.. | Appreciate If you can recreate the case in file/sample data so that it helps other help you..  ( :

Answer (score 0):

Add a time variable (eg NumberOfDaysInvested) and multiply it by percentage each investor had originally up until new investors join in. That's a more fair way to divide the profits.

However, it still remains a problem that new investors can partake in profits obtained earlier - ie after just being an investor for 1+ days you will gain access to profits made by earlier investors.

I would suggest to look into dividing investors into funds and pools to separate them but still introduce the time variable. It will reduce overall work on your side and will be more fair.